# How do you properly scale ImageView

Tags: android, view, imageview, scaling

ALL,

I am developing an application on Android where I need to load an image from the web and present it to the user in a ListView along with some other stuff. So I made 2 XML files (for row and whole display), wrote code to get the image and wrote the appropriate adapter.

Here is what I have:

product_line.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/product_picture"
    android:contentDescription="@string/product_picture"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/product_picture"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_price"
    android:layout_below="@id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_to_cart"
    android:layout_below="@id/product_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_to_cart"
/>
```

Unfortunately, upon running the code I see that the view is much bigger than the downloaded image and so takes a lot of spaces despite the "wrap_content" settings.

Is it possible to somehow set the view dimensions to display everything properly?

Thank you.

[EDIT]
I found this: http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/, but unfortunately it doesn't make any differences.
[/EDIT]

Comment: Do you want to scale up image to fill entire view with keeping aspect ratio of image?

Comment: @Dimmerg, No I want to downscale view so that the image will exactly fit into the view with keeping aspect ration of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale down your image view use:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:maxWidth="32dp" <!--set the width you wish to be -->
```

Comment: I don't want to set the width/height of the view. It should be set automatically to the width/height of the image. This is what I want.

Comment: Never mind. The image itself is huge. I might ask someone to change the image itself so that the system won't have to scale it.